# Generate UTFGrid from same source like map tiles

Tags: maps, tilemill

I know that TileMill/CartoCSS (Mapnik XML) can generate UTFGrid together with map tiles.

Now I'd like to generate UTFGrid either to one MBTiles file or to many JSON files - alongside the map tiles and accoding to the MBTiles spec. (Leaflet will do the map client work with infoboxes etc.): Anybody?

Comment: I have also been looking for such a solution, I was looking at this project: https://github.com/Ecotrust/create-utfgrids but I have not tried it

Answer (score 0):

> Now I'd like to generate UTFGrid either to one MBTiles file or to many JSON files - alongside the map tiles and accoding to the MBTiles spec.

It's not clear what you're wanting: a MBTiles file (as TileMill does by default) or many JSON files? If the latter, use TileMill to export your tiles as MBTiles and unpack the with [mb-util](https://github.com/mapbox/mbutil) or similar.